# ArcPy add point to a FeatureServer Layer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

What is the best practice to add a point to a FeatureServer Layer using arcpy? using rest services, write to db, etc? Where can I find a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Figured I could add some examples here.
Here is my sde connection module.
https://github.com/marigolds6/pythonintro/blob/master/sdeconn.py
This allows you to create an sde connection (stored in temp directories) with a call as simple as

```
from sdeconn import connect
dwsde = connect("stlco_sde_dw","sssgisdb10") #Connection to datawarehouse 10.1
#dwsde is a string providing a path to the temp connection file created
```

And here's a rather complicated example of harvesting rows from a sql server instance, standardizing the addresses attached to those rows, geocoding those address, adding time of day based on sun position, validating based on jurisdiction, and then writing the output.
https://github.com/marigolds6/pythonintermediate/blob/master/geocodecrimes.py

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. For hundreds of points the best practice is to use SQL and ArcPy. Only use rest in case you don't have access to the server. I end up using ArcPy.

Note that you will need to use arcpy.env.workspace and point to the SDE file, everything else is via arcpy.da.InsertCursor.